# R studio code giving me error after adding xlab and ylab

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to improve this code

```
ggplot(SurveyGenderDegree,aes(x=Education, y=Rate_of_Knowledge, xlab="Participants level of education", ylab="Participants rate of knowledge))+geom_point()+theme(text = element_text(size = 10),
axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1))
```

This code is giving me an error but I don't know why. It works ok when I take xlab and ylab out. Also how can I put some colour on this. I just need to improve it a bit for my uni assignment. Thanks

The more I play around with it the more error I get.

Comment: `xlab` and `ylab` are functions or layers in ggplot's parlance, not aesthetics. Try `ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + xlab("etc") + ylab("etc")`.

Comment: Alternatively, `ggplot(...) + labs(x="education", y="knowledge", title="something", subtitle="something else", caption="below the plot")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this could solve your labs problem, but your example is not reproducible (we do not have access to you data frame).

Use the **ggplot2::labs()** function, and you can also set the color of your plot in **ggplot2::geom_point()** function.

```
ggplot(SurveyGenderDegree,
           aes(x=Education, 
               y=Rate_of_Knowledge))+
      geom_point(color = "green") +
      labs(x = "Participants level of education",
           y = "Participants rate of knowledge") +
      theme(text = element_text(size = 10),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Is there an option to change the color to make it all different colours for xlab please? I changed green to group but gives error again  Thanks

Comment: I messed it up again 

Comment: ggplot(SurveyGenderDegree,
       aes(x=Education, 
           y=Rate_of_Knowledge, color=zone))+
  geom_point()+scale_colour_manual(values=setNames(Education, zone)) +
  labs(x = "Participants level of education",
       y = "Participants rate of knowledge") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1))

Comment: ha ha I hate R 

Comment: I have 5 groups in education with an n/a which I try to take out with this code below but n/a is still there 

Comment: ggplot(SurveyGenderDegree,
       aes(x=Education, 
           y=Rate_of_Knowledge))+
  geom_point(colour="green", na.rm = TRUE)+
  labs(x = "Participants level of education",
       y = "Participants rate of knowledge") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1))

Comment: Could you please share an reproducible example of your data so I can provide you the best aswer?

Comment: Thank you Lucas for all your help. I've sorted it now myself 